# ListView items changes when scrolling

Tags: java, android

I'm filling a listview, here is the code :

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> listAdapter1;
ListView toc;
toc=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listAdapter1=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(Glossary.this,R.array.arabicalphabet,R.layout.glossarysimplerow);
toc.setAdapter(listAdapter1);
```

I'm setting a list selector in the xml file, when clicking on any item in the list its color will change to blue to show that it is selected. The problem is, when I scroll the listview the selection will change, for example if I have a list filled from A to Z, If I select the letter "B" and I scroll many times, I get the letter "M" selected...
Any help please

Comment: add the adapter code. You should use the ViewHolder pattern or make sure you have defined both the if (something) -> change color to blue and also the else -> change back to whatever color you want as default.

Comment: Please post your full adapter code.. if not please use the BaseAdpater with viewholder pattern.

Comment: i think this is happening due to the recycling of views,maintain a boolean for each item state that it is selected or not

Comment: Guys there is no java adapter code, only the code I've posted

Comment: Check out this for idea : http://stackoverflow.com/users/2738565/haresh-chhelana?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=2

Comment: Have you tried `ArrayAdapter`, layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice` and setting choice mode to multiple

Answer (score 2):

In Android the children of `AdapterView` like `ListView` have caching enabled, so when user scrolls, the items off the screen are off the memory, `getView()` is called for the items that are to be shown on the view after scrolling.

The `View` that is passed in the `getView()` method is reused and has properties of the previously visible `view`s in the `ListView`. This improves the performance of the `ListView` but makes it necessary to check for all the possible conditions and reset all the properties of the view received in the `getView()`.

Now the generic `ArrayAdapter` that you used has no implementation of changing colors on click and it doesn't have any way to keep a record of the view already clicked. So on scrolling the results are unexpected.

You may implement your own `Adapter` class as shown below and it will solve your issue:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    List<String> lstStrings;
    List<Boolean> isClicked;

    public MyAdapter (Context context, int resource, List<String> lstStrings) {
        super(context, resource, lstStrings);
        this.context = context;
        lstStrings = lstStrings;
        isClicked = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Boolean[lstStrings.length]));
        Collections.fill(isClicked, new Boolean(false));
    }   

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return lstStrings.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return lstStrings.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from( context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        TextView txtTheText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTheText);

        txtTheText .setText(lstStrings.get(position));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                isClicked.set(!isClicked.get(position));
            }
        });

        if (isClicked.get(position))
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 0, 0));
        else
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 255));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing just a typo, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

yah, I encounted this problem a week ago, the reason is "when you scroll listview, the first display item has position 0", so your change view will affect on the new item.

My solution is:

1). Using `ScrollView` with a `LinearLayout` inside it instead of using `ListView`

2). Add array `TextView[]` to `LinearLayout`.

code:

Layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_inflater"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Java:

```
int prePos = -1;
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
LinearLayout ll_inflater = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_inflater);
TextView[] tv_Subs = new TextView[array.size()];//arrary is arrayData
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
    tv_Subs[i] = new TextView(getApplication());
    tv_Subs[i].setLines(3);
    tv_Subs[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sub_color));
    tv_Subs[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        //set default background color
    } else {
        //set default background color
    }

    tv_Subs[i].setText(array.get(i));
    ll_inflater.addView(tv_Subs[i], i, new  ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT));
    final int finalI = i;
    tv_Subs[i].setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(prePos !=-1){
                 //change background of preposition tv_Subs[prePost] to default color
            }
            //change background color here
            prePos = finalI;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem is I must use a listview, is there a way to work it out ?

Comment: I don't have another solution. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a resolution. When you click one item, record its `position`. Then override `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)`, and call `ListView.setSelection(position)`.